# Django Admin: Restrict staff to update

Tags: django, django-admin

I had a `Blog Model`. All new blog post has `DRAFT` status.

In the admin page, admin would be all permissions (CRUD) on the `Blog Model`. I can solve this by using Django's `register` method.

What I want is `is_staff` user can view all the `Blog Post` but can't update Status (Eg. from `DRAFT` to `APPROVE`).

Is there any way to check the `request`'s group, then allow the user to update or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to mark the `status` field as read only in the admin class, by setting [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import BlogPost

@admin.register(BlogPost):
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('status',)
```

Note that this makes `status` read-only for ALL admin users. If you need more fine-grained control based on the current user, there is a [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields) method you can override.

Also, since ALL users of the Django Admin have `is_staff`, we'll explicitly check for the [built-in permission to change a `BlogPost`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions).

```py
class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # obj is None if we're creating a new BlogPost, or a BlogPost instance
        # if we are editing an existing BlogPost
        if not request.user.has_perm("your_app.change_blogpost"):
            return ("status",)
        return []
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I am going to try your solution.